# Color Fill with R VennDiagram: "Unexpected parameter length for 'fill'"

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, data-visualization, venn-diagram

I use a Venn Diagram to visualize the overlap between `values_one` and `values_two`.

The default outcome is black-and-white, but I want to fill it with colors. Based on [this tutorial](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/14-venn-diagramm.html), I use `RColorBrewer`; however, I get the following error message:

> **Error in VennDiagram::draw.pairwise.venn(area1 = length(x[[1](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/14-venn-diagramm.html)]), area2 = length(x[[2]]),  :
> Unexpected parameter length for 'fill'**

What did I do wrong, how can I fix it?

Thank you for your help!

```
# ------------------
# reproducible values
# ------------------
values_one <- c("Physical Review B", "IFAC Papersonline", "Journal Of High Energy Physics", 
"Physical Review Letters", "Nuclear Fusion", "Physics Letters B")

values_two <- c("Lecture Notes", "Optics Infobase Conference Papers", "Physical Review B", "IFAC Papersonline", "Journal Of High Energy Physics", "Physical Review Letters")

# ------------------
# create VennDiagram
# ------------------
library("VennDiagram")
library("RColorBrewer")

myCol <- brewer.pal(3, "Pastel2")

venn.diagram(x = list(values_one, values_two)
             , category.names = c("WoS", "Scopus")
             , filename = paste0(filePath, "venn2019.png")
             , output=T
             , fill=myCol)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try limiting `myCol` to two hex codes instead of three.

**Edit:**

Because RColorBrewer::brewer.pal has a lower limit on number of colors you can choose directly (n > 2), in case you want only one or two colors, you first need to specify the palette you want to use and *then* subset the specific hex codes. For example like so:

```r
myCol <- brewer.pal(8, "Pastel2")[c(1, 2)]
myCol <- brewer.pal(8, "Pastel2")[c(1, 8)] # Or any other nice-looking combination
```

Comment: Thanks; this unfortunately doesn't work: **In brewer.pal(2, "Pastel2") :minimal value for n is 3, returning requested palette with 3 different levels**. (In addition, the Venn Diagram should show two circles with *three* spaces because of the central overlap.)

Comment: Yes, very true. Try `brewer.pal(8, "Pastel2")[c(1, 2)]` or similar to pull out only the two hex codes from Pastel2 that you want. The color of the central overlap will be determined by those two, I think.

Comment: Well, that's perfect, it works. Thank you so much! Do you want to edit this solution into your post so that I can upvote and accept it?